# Avoid empty cells on CSV export for varying row length

Tags: excel, csv, vba

My rows do not have the same length and I need to avoid the "blanks" in between when I export to CSV.

For example, when I export this:

> 1 2   3   4   5
>
> 1 2
>
> 1 3   3   4
>
> 1 2   3   4   5

I get this:

> 1,2,3,4,5
>
> 1,2,,,
>
> 1,3,3,4,
>
> 1,2,3,4,5

And I need to remove the extra seperators from the empty cells between.
I am already running a macro to export as CSV, so it would be best if I could "delete" the empty cells in the beginning of this.

Comment: Those extra separators have to be there to have a valid csv.

Comment: Is there a way to get around this then? Or delete them from the csv afterwards?

Comment: If you're using vba, you could as well generate the file from code, or trim the trailing comma's. But it shouldn't be called a csv, or be used as a csv then. And if it has to be used as a csv, the comma's can be left in there.

Comment: well its an export from ABB microSCADA HMI configuration tool, here there are not seperators in those cells. 
And when I later make the import the only valid files are "*.csv" and it returns an error if there are seperators in those fields. So i guess its ABBs fault then, but since I proberbly cant make them change this I have to make a work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was pretty simple to solve, I just added a loop to check and delete if the last symbol in a line was a seperator

```
With Selection
StartRow = .Cells(1).Row
StartCol = .Cells(1).Column
EndRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
EndCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
End With
Else
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
StartRow = .Cells(1).Row
StartCol = .Cells(1).Column
EndRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
EndCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
End With
End If

For RowNdx = StartRow To EndRow
WholeLine = ""
For ColNdx = StartCol To EndCol
If Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = "" Then
CellValue = ""
Else
CellValue = Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value
End If
WholeLine = WholeLine & CellValue & Sep
Next ColNdx
WholeLine = Left(WholeLine, Len(WholeLine) - Len(Sep))

//I added this to delete the last seperator in a line before printing
Dim last As String
last = Right(WholeLine, 1)
Do Until last <> ","
WholeLine = Left(WholeLine, Len(WholeLine) - 1)
last = Right(WholeLine, 1)
Loop

Print #nFileNum, WholeLine
Next RowNdx
```

Answer (score 1):

This small macro will:

- avoid creating empty *CSV* records corresponding to empty Excel rows
- avoid trailing commas

```
Option Explicit

Sub CSV_Makerr()
   Dim r As Range
   Dim sOut As String, k As Long, M As Long
   Dim N As Long, nFirstRow As Long, nLastRow As Long
   Dim MyFilePath As String, MyFileName As String
   Dim fs, a, mm As Long
   Dim separator As String

   ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
   nFirstRow = r.Row
   separator = ","

   MyFilePath = "C:\TestFolder\"
   MyFileName = "whatever"
   Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(MyFilePath & MyFileName & ".csv", True)

   For N = nFirstRow To nLastRow
       k = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells(N, 1).EntireRow)
       sOut = ""
       If k = 0 Then

       Else
           M = Cells(N, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
           For mm = 1 To M
               sOut = sOut & Cells(N, mm).Text & separator
           Next mm
           sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 1)
           a.writeline (sOut)
       End If
   Next

   a.Close
End Sub
```